# Problemas con manipulación de archivo CSV usando C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, csv

Estoy prácticamente haciendo un *ABC* de un archivo `CSV` mediante un GUI interactivo. Ya tengo el alta, pero se me está dificultando hacer la baja y mostrar los datos en un `datagridview`.

Para la baja tengo este código pero sólo borra el campo en el que lo contiene la línea.

**Ejemplo de archivo `CSV`**:

```
ID,Nombre,Apellido,Pais
1,David,tod,Mex
2,Juan,Perez,Arg
3,Pepe,Lopez,Col
```

---

Primera iteración **Baja** mandando el `id` `1` para borrar la linea, queda así:

```
David,tod,Mex
2,Juan,Perez,Arg
3,Pepe,Lopez,Col
```

Sólo borra el `id` que busco, pero no toda la línea

---

El **resultado esperado** sería que quede así:

```
ID,Nombre,Apellido,Pais
2,Juan,Perez,Arg
3,Pepe,Lopez,Col
```

---

**Código**:

```cs
string busqueda = "1";

string[] values = File.ReadAllText("C:\\registros.csv").Split(new char[] { ',' });
StringBuilder ObjStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    if (values[i].Contains(busqueda))
        continue;
    ObjStringBuilder.Append(values[i] + ",");
}
ObjStringBuilder.ToString().Remove(ObjStringBuilder.Length - 1);
File.WriteAllText("\\registros.csv", ObjStringBuilder.ToString());
```

---

Otra duda es cómo puedo mostrar el archivo `CSV` en un `datagridview` en Windows Forms. Tengo esta lógica, pero ¿cómo puedo mostrarla?

```cs
public DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable()
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("\\registros.csv");
    string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    foreach (string header in headers)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(header);
    }
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string[] rows = Regex.Split(sr.ReadLine(), ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = rows[i];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es tu código modificado para exportar el CSV borrando la fila según el ID:

```
string busqueda = "1";

string[] values = File.ReadAllText("registros.csv").Split(new char[] { '\n' });
StringBuilder ObjStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    if (values[i].Split(',')[0] == busqueda)
        continue;
    ObjStringBuilder.AppendLine(values[i].TrimEnd('\r'));
}
File.WriteAllText("registros.csv", ObjStringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] {'\n','\r'}),Encoding.UTF8);
```

y para mostrar el resultado de `ConvertCSVtoDataTable` sólo tienes que asignarlo al datagrid:

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = ConvertCSVtoDataTable()
```

Aquí la variación del código que usa la columna 1 del array y comprueba que la fila al menos tenga dos posiciones.

```
        string busqueda = "10.76.54.32";

        string[] values = File.ReadAllText("registros.csv").Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        StringBuilder ObjStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] resultado = values[i].Split(',');
            if (resultado.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hay una fila que no cumple el patron Sistema,IPSistema,User,Pass ! por favor revise el CSV origen   nº de fila {0}", i);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (resultado[1] == busqueda)
                    continue;
            }
            ObjStringBuilder.AppendLine(values[i].TrimEnd('\r'));
        }
        File.WriteAllText("registros.csv", ObjStringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }), Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine("Proceso finalizado, pulsa enter para continuar.");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Saludos,

Comment: Que tal David, la solucion me es correcta pero en una segunda iteracion borra toda la informacion del csv :(

Comment: @David Porqueras y @David Tod esa forma es riesgosa porque se borrarán todas las líneas en las que aparezca el "1" en el `ID`: 1; 10; 11; etc.

Comment: Es verdad, tiene un bug :( ahora mismo pongo una solución. @Aprendiendo.NET

Comment: @DavidTod acabo de probar con varias iteraciones y veo que funciona correctamente, ejecutas el código siempre sobre el mismo archivo? es decir el archivo de entrada es el de salida?

Comment: Asi es @DavidPorqueras ya que si agrego un nuevo csv en cada ejecución tomaria el que tiene todos los registros (registros.csv) solo eliminaria uno (David) y en la siguiente ejecución en otro borrado diferente (Juan) volveria el registro que ya habia borrado anteriormente (David) y si sigue borrando todos los registros en la segunda ejecución manteniendo el path registro.csv :(

Comment: Has probado con la ultima versión del código que he posteado?  yo paso el proceso varias veces y el archivo resultante es correcto, incluso con el mismo archivo en entrada y salida.

Comment: @David Porqueras se ve correcta la nueva versión, pero puedes ahorrarte los `TrimEnd` si el `Split` sobre `values` lo realizas con el `string NewLine` o `\r\n` en lugar de solo `\n`. También habría que pedirle a @David Tod que especifique las reglas del CSV, ya que con este algoritmo no podrá usar la coma ni el `string NewLine` dentro de los campos.

Comment: @DavidPorqueras Mi ejemplo lo puse muy basico pero realmente lo que quiero es borrar una ip como tipo de búsqueda que seria la columna [1], pero me pone que esta fuera del rango del index cuando pongo una ip tipo 10.115.63.22 borra perfectamente la posición [0] con un string tipo nombre, no se si sea por los puntos que tiene el string?

Comment: pues no tiene mucho sentido lo que cuentas ¿puedes postear los datos con los que estas probando ahora?

Comment: @DavidPorqueras ya publique una respuesta a ver si me puedes ayudar, estamos cercas !

Comment: @DavidPorqueras +1, aunque cabe aclarar que no funcionaría en casos donde se usan comillas para incluir una coma dentro de un campo (aunque no parecería ser el caso según el ejemplo del autor).

Comment: Funciono perfectamente gracias de nuevo @DavidPorqueras :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok este es en realidad mi CSV puse el otro por fines practicos, lo que quiero eliminar, es la IP que esta en la columna IPSistema

```
Sistema,IPSistema,User,Pass
W7,10.123.45.67,admin,1234
WXP,10.76.54.32,admin,1234
W7,10.11.22.33,admin,1234
```

Tu codigo @DavidPorqueras funciona correctamente eliminando la primera columna como parametro (Sistemas) mandado desde una busqueda = textbox.Text, que por la logica que veo pones como columna la posicion [0] (Sistema) y la elimina correctamente si pondria WXP en el textbox

```
if (values[i].Split(',')[0] == busqueda)
```

Y lo que quiero es eliminarla con una IP como busqueda entonces opte por cambiar el codigo por columna [1] que seria la de IPSistema

```
if (values[i].Split(',')[1] == busqueda)
```

pero me marca error de que excedió la longitud del array en esa linea, y solo se podría eliminar como en el primer ejemplo, como podria borrar la ip de ese csv? comparando la variable busqueda

Y Gracias por el codigo David

Comment: @Mariano no me parecería correcto que cerraran la pregunta ya que es la lógica de David y el es que mas podría acercarse a la respuesta, y no crear mas confusión con otro usuario. Consideralo Mariano por favor

Comment: Te agrego un nuevo código en la respuesta principal que comprueba que existan al menos las columnas 0 y 1 para hacer el borrado, en caso que no existan muestra un error.